# Simple PHP web crawler returning simple HTML DOM error

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have a PHP script that returns links on a webpage. I am getting 500 internal error and this is what my server logs say. I let my friend try the same code on his server and it seems to run correctly. Can someone help me debug my problem? The warning says something about the wrapper is disabled. I checked line 1081 but I do not see `allow_url_fopen`.

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /hermes/bosweb/web066/b669/ipg.streamversetv/simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.dota2lounge.com/): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /hermes/bosweb/web066/b669/ipg.streamversetv/simple_html_dom.php on line 1081
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /hermes/bosweb/web066/b669/ipg.streamversetv/sim

```
<?php
 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
 $target_url = 'http://www.dota2lounge.com/';
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file($target_url);
  foreach($html->find(a) as $link){
    echo $link->href.'<br />';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Server disabled the option to use `file_get_contents()` with remote files.

Comment: The errors message are VERY clear. Line 1081 is where you're ATTEMPTING to use a url in an fopen context. You need to look in your php.ini to enable the setting.

Comment: Where can I find my php.ini?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is a setting parameter in php.ini

Comment: Nevermind I found it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

1. Download latest simple_html_dom.php: [LINK TO DOWNLOAD](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
2. Open simple_html_dom.php in your favourite editor and add this code to the first couple of line(can be added right after `<?php`):

   ```php
   function file_get_contents_curl($url) {

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);     

       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);

       return $data; }
   ```
3. Find line starting with `function file_get_html($url.....` for me it is line 71, but you can use search in your editor as well. (search for file_get_html)
4. Edit this line(some lines below after function file_get_html):

   `$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);`

   to this:

   `$contents = file_get_contents_curl($url);`
5. Instead of load_file, use file_get_html an it will work for you, without editing php.ini

Comment: Please clarify 5th point. where to use "file_get_html" instead of "load_file" ? @DB5

Comment: @SikandarAliChishty I only edited this answer to make the formatting clearer. p.tamas is the one who wrote the answer, you’ll need to direct your question to him.

Comment: Please clarify 5th point. where to use "file_get_html" instead of "load_file" ? @p.tamas

Comment: I had the same error in log, changing to the curl version it works now fine.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more, really good solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `allow_url_fopen` php setting to 1 to allow using `fopen()` with urls.

Reference: [PHP: Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

**Edit:**
Also tracked down another thing, have you tried loading this way?

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.dota2lounge.com/');

    foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
    {
        echo $link->href.'<br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I just changed, allow_url_fopen = 1. Still getting 500 error, should I allow some time for my server to change?

Comment: What happens when you test it now? If you still get the same message, it's probably because you need to change it in your php.ini settings and restart the server.

Comment: I'm still getting the 500 error, I'm not sure what the actual error is because my log isn't updated yet. How would I go about to resetting a server? I have my website hosted on ipage.com

Comment: You can try adding this line to your .htaccess instead: `php_value allow_url_fopen On` it may not work, depending on how your server is configured. By the way, 500 is a server error, so if you're trying to connect to someone else's site, their .htaccess might be preventing you from accessing the file.

Comment: Here is the new error im getting.   20130927T131614: stre/crawler.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in ipg.htfhft/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113

Comment: The html isn't loading, I've taken a look at the Simple HTML DOM website (As I should have done, originally) and I've updated my post with how they show it being used.

Comment: I have followed all steps, but still same issue in this line:         `$this->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);` I think have to replace this line too but I don't know how.